# Scalar query for fetching records from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am having a table as tbl_employee with columns id, name, bco and wco respectively.
bco and wco have int values as their data type.

I have a table tbl_country with columns cid and country

i Wnt to fetch the record as

```
Name        Bco       WCO
==========================
Raj         India     USA
```

Comment: I Git the issue resolved the query is as Below

Answer (score 0):

This needs joining the `tbl_country` two times something as below. Note that the query is using `inner join` so both `bco` and `wco` should have matching record in `country` table, if not then just use `left join` instead.

```
select
e.name,
c1.country as Bco,
c2.country as WCO
from tbl_employee  e
join tbl_country c1 on c1.cid = e.bco
join tbl_country c2 on c2.cid = e.wco
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_employee.id,tbl_employee.name,tbl_country.countryName 
  as BCO,tbl_country.countryName as WCO 
FROM tbl_employee 
LEFT JOIN tbl_country ON tbl_country.id = tbl_employee.bco 
RIGHT JOIN tbl_country ON tbl_country.id = tbl_employee.wco
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl_employee.name AS name, lookup_bco.country AS Bco, lookup_wco.country AS WCO
FROM tbl_employee
INNER JOIN tbl_country AS lookup_bco ON tbl_employee.bco = lookup_bco.cid
INNER JOIN tbl_country AS lookup_wco ON tbl_employee.wco = lookup_wco.cid
```

Comment: Good remark of Abhik Chakraborty: 'Note that the query is using inner join so both bco and wco should have matching record in country table, if not then just use left join instead.'